# Thymeleaf- Create dynamic id for table row

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and I am trying to create id for `tr` and getting dynamic rows.

Successfully getting table rows but I don't know hot to create id for each row in Thymeleaf.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table">
  <thead style="background-color:#CCE5FF">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Created Date</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr th:each="emp,iterStat : ${empList}">
    <td th:text="${emp.id}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${emp.mdrcode}">Code</td>
    <td th:text="${emp.createDate}">Created Date</td>
    <td>
      <a id="editview" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" th:href="@{/}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> View</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `th:id` for that.

```
<!-- this would assign the emp.id to the id attribute of the tr.
<tr th:id="${emp.id}" th:each="emp,iterStat : ${empList}">
    <td th:text="${emp.id}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${emp.mdrcode}">Code</td>
    <td th:text="${emp.createDate}">Created Date</td>
    <td><a  id="editview" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" th:href="@{/}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> View</a></td>
</tr>
```

We can also add some text to the id:

```
<!-- this would assign someText + emp.id to the id attribute of the tr.
<tr th:id="'someText' + ${emp.id}" th:each="emp,iterStat : ${empList}">
    <td th:text="${emp.id}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${emp.mdrcode}">Code</td>
    <td th:text="${emp.createDate}">Created Date</td>
    <td><a  id="editview" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" th:href="@{/}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> View</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine. But any possibility to display this is in alert box by using jquery?

Comment: you could add a class to those `tr` tags, add a click listener to them and get the id by using `.attr('id')`

Comment: This is not best practice. This solution has security vulnerability as id is visible to hackers.

Comment: @ImaMiri could you be more specific about that pls?

Comment: @TommySchmidt You can code this way for tutorials but for real application, you should use randomId or sth like that. Because Ids are usually sequential and vulnerable to xss attacks.

Comment: @ImaMiri that's just speculation. we're never using sequential ids at work and usually the id is readonly (and generated by the server not by the user). i dont see how that would be vulnearable to xss. anyway i think that's out of scope for this question